# Too many parameters error, but called with correct amount

Tags: python-2.7, webapp2

got a question about this error:

```
TypeError: rot13() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Which occurs on this code:

```
def get(self): <-- called on every get request
    ch = self.rot13("abc")

def rot13(input): <-- fairly untested rot 13 ;)
    alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
         'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    escaped = escape(input)
    ciphered = ""
    for char in escaped:
        originalIndex = alpha.index(char)
        newIndex = (originalIndex + 13) % 26
        ciphered = chipered + alpha[newIndex]
```

Do not know why there is this error. I'm just handing one parameter there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're missing this:

```
def rot13(self, input):
```

… That's because `rot13()` appears to be a *method* inside a class, not a stand-alone function, so it needs to receive `self`.

Comment: Oh yeah :) beginner's mistake. Is this python or webapp2 specific?

Comment: It's Python-specific :)

Comment: A thank you. Will accept once the 10mins are over. (coming from other langs, this is really odd)